# Append nested list from one dictionary to a nested list of another dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I have 2 dictionaries:

```
a = {'name': 'Bob', 'values': ['abcd']}
b = {'name': 'Jack', 'values': ['efg']}
```

**Desired output:**

```
b = {'name': 'Jack', 'values': ['abcd','efg']}
```

**Current code:**  (undesired output)

```
b['values'].append(a['values'])

print(b)
>>>{'name': 'Jack', 'values': ['abcd', ['efg']]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't append, you should add the elements instead:

```
b['values']+=a['values']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the `extend` method of `lists` like:

```
b['values'].extend(a['values'])

>>> b
{'name': 'Jack', 'values': ['efg', 'abcd']}
```